# Azure Service Fabric Cluster connection with on premise network (Private data center)

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Can you please describe the process on how services inside Service Fabric Cluster could communicate with the database servers present in our private datacenter?

Right now how we do for some of the custom VMs on Azure is that we attach network interfaces(NICs) to VMs and Nics are connected to the subnet which provides us cross premises connectivity.

Is there any way we could specify this when provisioning the Service Fabric Cluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the preferred way - Have a VNET that is connected to your datacenter (either with S2S VPN or Express Route), and then you are free to access on-prem resources from your code as if you were operating inside the local network. You don't have to *add* NICs to your SF VMs, you can just modify the ARM template to provision all resources inside the designated VNET.

If you take a look at the [sample template for SF](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-unsecure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype/azuredeploy.json), you can see the `subnet0Ref` variable which is being used to set the network profile of the NICs that are part of the newly created scale set.
You can modify the template to lookup your pre-existing subnet using the `resourceid` template expression function ([documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#resourceid)). The you can drop from the template all the other resources that you don't need created, like the VNET itself.